# Python ,how to link a progress bar to distutils.dir_util.copy_tree

Tags: python, python-2.7

I made a little app, basically at certain point I call the distutils.dir_util.copy_tree which copy the file to the destination. Would anyone help me to link a basic progress bar such as:

```
[======]50%
```

to the copy process... unfortunately I can't guess I long it's gonna take to copy the folder-tree since it 's gonna be different from time to time.
Thanks in advance to anyone who will answer me.

Answer (score 3):

`distutils.dir_util.copy_tree()` does not provide a callback that you can use for this. You will need to use `os.walk()` in order to enumerate the filesystem objects and then use `shutil.copy[2]()` to copy the actual objects.

Comment: thanks Ignacio, I thought I could ad a simple progress bar inside the distutils.dir_util.copy_tree() 'foor loop'... isn't that possible?

Comment: @nassio, you'll need to split it into two passes anyway - you need to know the total number of files before you start copying.

Answer (score 0):

Corey Glodberg wrote about a simple lib for doing ascii progress bar on command line aplications, maybe you could find it interesting:

http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com.es/2010/01/python-command-line-progress-bar-with.html

Answer (score 0):

As explained in Python's doc, you can provide a callback to shutil.copytree.

```
from shutil import copytree

def _countFiles(path, names):
    #do someting with "path" and "names"
    return []   # nothing will be ignored

copytree(source, destination, ignore=_countFiles)
```

I've not written code to get progress, but you get the point :

1. count files in your directory (and sub directories)
2. in "_countFiles", increment the number of processed files
3. progress = nb_processed_files * 100 / nb_total_files

Regards

Comment: This is incorrect. The Python docs clearly state that the ignore callable is called once per (sub)directory that is copied, passing the directory and list of files into the callable. This does not provide a mechanism for progress because it's called once per directory, not per file. Say you had 10,000 files in one directory. the ignore would be called once to see which files to ignore and never again, leaving no ability to track progress.

Comment: That's a good point. At least you have progress by directory :)